# Spring Boot, Lazy Loading is Creating Different Object for same identifier

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I just migrate from "just" hibernate to Spring Boot. I have some problem in using lazy loading one-to-many relationship.

Consider I create these classes:

**SalesQuot class**

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "sales_quot" )
public class SalesQuot{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private long id = 0;

    @OneToMany(fetch= FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=SalesQuotSub.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="salesQuot", orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<SalesQuotSub> subs;
}
```

**-SalesQuotSub class**

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "sales_quot_sub" )
public class SalesQuotSub{

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="sales_quot")
    private SalesQuot salesQuot;
}
```

I use CRUDRepository and this configuration to enable lazy loading

> ("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", true)

Then, consider I have 1 SalesQuot instance which has 3 SalesQuotSub instances as its child

```
salesQuot.subs = { sub1, sub2, sub3 }
```

All saved to database, everthing is fine. 
The problem occur when I try to load them from database. Lazy load is working fine, but the real parent instance (salesQuot) and parent taken from child's parent properties (eg: sub1.salesQuot) have different value. 
Example of print result:

```
salesQuot = sales.quotation.SalesQuot@2f3f1bfa
sub1.salesQuot = sales.quotation.SalesQuot@22be2326
sub2.salesQuot = sales.quotation.SalesQuot@22be2326
sub3.salesQuot = sales.quotation.SalesQuot@22be2326
```

What I want is they should return the same object. Could u guys help me with this?

Never meet this in 'just' Hibernate, Sorry for poor English.
Thank You in advance.

PS: I have tried using EAGER fetching, everything works fine, they return the same parent instance.

Comment: Up Up Up Still not solved